# Transplant into workspace without commiting

Tags: mercurial, transplant

Is there a way to have transplant a single changeset without commiting? 
I'd like to be able to review the changes prior to doing a commit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`hg transplant`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/TransplantExtension) always results in a new changeset in your repository.

However, you could:

1. Use [`hg export`](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#export) and [`hg import --no-commit`](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#import) instead OR
2. Use `hg transplant` and then [`hg strip`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/StripExtension) if you don't like the changeset

Comment: `hg export -o - -r <change> | hg import --no-commit -`

Answer (score 3):

Found this question when searching for "graft without commit".

I've found I can do what I want by updating to the changeset where I want the changes to be on top of, then using the "hg revert" command.

So if I have changeset "R1" then I commit a "R2" I can put the R2 changes back into the working directory by doing:

- hg update -r R1  <-- (this puts your working directory in exact state you want to start from)
- hg revert --all -r R2  <-- (this applies the changes in R2 to the working directory, without committing those changes)

You can then strip the R2 changeset if you want or do whatever you want.

Comment: Wouldn't `hg revert --all -r R2` do much more than cherrypick `R2` into the current changeset without committing? IIUC, it would completely overwrite any changes made to the files in `R1`, replacing the entire files with whatever contents they have in `R2`?